# Excel - how to count how many times a word appears within a certain date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have a spreadsheet that contains all my workout data and each row has the following columns:

*date that the exercise was performed
*name of the exercise
*body part trained: **back**, **shoulders**, **chest**

I am trying to create a function that will search all rows in a given date range and return back the amount of times that a certain body part was trained during that period of time.

For example: I would like to find out how many times I trained my **back** between 01/08/22 and 15/08/22.

It's very easy to find out the total amount of times that I trained my back across all data by using a simple countif statement however I can't find how to do that for certain date ranges.

Thank you for your time and help.

Ilias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You should use [COUNTIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function.

> The COUNTIFS function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times all criteria are met.

On the example below, the criteria are on column E. The comparison is done with the lower and upper limit of the date range and the body part, and returns the count.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A16,">=" & E2,A2:A16,"<=" & E3,B2:B16,E4)
```

[image]

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is better to use `...,A2:A16,"<" & (E3+1),...` as the second condition - this will avoid errors if column A contains not only the date, but the date-time

Comment: @JohnSUN Good suggestion.

Comment: Reddy thank you both so much that solved it! I tried to use the countifs before but was missing the last part of the argument. @JohnSUN thats a great suggestion too, I actually had to remove the time from the date using a =Left so thats simplifies things more